# Probability of selecting two trucks

Tags: probability

An automobile manufacturing plant produced $31$ vehicles today: $11$ were sedans, $11$ were vans, and $9$ were trucks. Plant managers are going to choose two of these vehicles for a thorough inspection. The first vehicle will be chosen at random, and then the second vehicle will be chosen at random from the remaining vehicles. What is the probability that two trucks will be selected?

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and explain where you're stuck? Also, please use a descriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are

$\frac{31*30}{2}=465$

possibilities to choose 2 vehicles out of the 31, and

$\frac{9*8}{2}=36$ , such that two trucks are selected,

so the probability is

$\frac{36}{465}=\frac{12}{155}$.

The other way to calculate it :

At the first step, the probability if $\frac{9}{31}$ to choose a truck, at the
second step it is $\frac{8}{30}$ (if in the first step,a truck was chosen), so the probability of choosing two trucks is
$\frac{9}{31}*\frac{8}{30}=\frac{12}{155}$.

Comment: don't forget: it's sampling without replacement

Comment: Please edit the title!

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: you need two successes in two trials.

Hint 2: if he first vehicle selected is a truck, both the number of trucks and the total number of vehicles reduces by 1.